# tomcat user python module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, centos7

tomcat user or for that matter any user using python2 or python3 is unable to find boto3 module, whereas in running python2 or 3 from root works fine.

```
-bash-4.2$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named boto3
>>>
-bash-4.2$ whoami
tomcat
```

root user works

```
[root@server-name]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 16 2020, 22:23:17)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>>
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: Print the value of `sys.path` as both users, and see what the difference is.